# GA4: Is it possible to pre create events so they can be marked as conversions?

Tags: google-analytics-4

It takes 24 hours for a GA4 property to list the events it knows, and that won't include events that have not fired yet.

We want to be able to fully set up our clients GA4 properties on the day. But if the event is not listed we can't mark it as a conversion.

Is it possible to pre-add events like you have to do for definitions?